# Map Firestore DocumentSnapshot to Properties In a Class

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have code like this for QuerySnapshot to get documents in collection that works good.

```
List<DaftarHazard> _userHazardFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.documents.map((hazards) {
      return DaftarHazard(
          waktuHazard: hazards.data['waktuHazard'],
          judulHazard: hazards.data['judulHazard'],
          isiHazard: hazards.data['isiHazard'],
          fotoHazard: hazards.data['fotoHazard'],
          namaPelapor: hazards.data['namaPelapor'],
          lokasiHazard: hazards.data['lokasiHazard'],
          statusHazard: hazards.data['statusHazard']);
    }).toList();
  }

  Stream<List<DaftarHazard>> get userHazardAsSuper {
    return userHazards.snapshots().map(_userHazardFromSnapshot);

  }
```

But then I need to Map DocumentSnapshot to class properties.
I don't know how to get this done. 
How can I do this using the same method that I use for the QuerySnapshot?

The code above I get from collections.
Code below is the one I use to get fields in a document

```
Stream<List<UserDetails>> get userDetails {
    return userData.document(uid).snapshots().map(_userDetailsFromSnapshot);
  }
```

and using this to map to the properties

```
List<UserDetails> _userDetailsFromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.data.map((item) {
      return UserDetails(
        name: details.['name'],
        email: details.data['email'],
      );
    }).toList();
  }
```

But code above does not work.

Found the solutions here:
[Net Ninja](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eelKWYwUm5w&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9j--TKIdkb3ISfRbJeJYQwC&index=24)

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean "function properties"?

Comment: sorry I mean class properties.

Answer (score 0):

You to extract the data from your `DocumentSnapshot`.

```
List<DaftarHazard> _userHazardFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.documents.map((hazards) {
       return DaftarHazard(
          waktuHazard: hazards.data['waktuHazard'] != null ?  WaktuHazard.fromData(hazards.data['waktuHazard'].data) : null,
          judulHazard: hazards.data['judulHazard'],
          isiHazard: hazards.data['isiHazard'],
          fotoHazard: hazards.data['fotoHazard'],
          namaPelapor: hazards.data['namaPelapor'],
          lokasiHazard: hazards.data['lokasiHazard'],
          statusHazard: hazards.data['statusHazard']);
    }).toList();
  }
```

And replace each property for its own object instead of `DocumentSnapshots`.

I'm not sure of the structure that you want, but basically, you just need to access the `data` property of your `DocumentSnapshot` and parse it accordingly.

Comment: I have added the code I am trying to use. I think it is different when extract data from QuerySnapshot and DocumentSnapshot.

Comment: Your code does should work as intended. You can debug to see what `data` contains.

Comment: i get error: The argument type 'MapEntry<?, ?> Function(String)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic> Function(String, dynamic)'.

Comment: You should use `item.data` instead of `details.data` that I don't even know where it comes from.

Comment: yes, that I haven't edit yet. I use item.data but still not work. I found the solution for my problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution for getting field and value from a specific document in firestore here

```
[Net Ninja][1]
```